# Ploting graph with irregular X axis values

Tags: android, achartengine

I am using achartengine for data that my application is continuously receiving over a socket connection. The point are plotted one point at a time.
The only problem here is that my X axis data is not guaranteed to be in a sequence(ascending/descending).

eg: 350, 352, 356, 360, 1, 5, 10, 12, 18, ....., 349.

When i feed this data into my existing code the engine re-arranges the X axis. Its gets auto arranged to 1, 5, 10,....., 360. Hence the graph does not accurately describe the sequence of arrival of my data.

Is there a way in which i can preserve the sequence of the X axis.
The X axis markers in the graph should ideally be in the same sequence as it had arrived.

Comment: What if you swap X and Y? so that X increases with the time of arrival and Y is the value. Normally you would do like this.

Comment: Y axis data could be anything. eg: 2,8,1,4,9,2,0,8,... Swapping the X and Y will not solve my problem.
Actually the X axis data is the angles in a circle and the Y axis data is the associated value at that angle. The user can start drawing the circle from any point until he completes the circle.

Comment: So what is X value? not an increasing value? because I guess that X is **supposed** to be automatically reordered in an increasing way...

Answer (score 1):

I had to do a similar thing. What you need to do is disable the auto-x-axis numbering and give it your own labels:

```
private void setXLabels(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer, String[] labels, int[] values) {
    renderer.setXLabels(0);
    renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
    for(int i = 0; i < labels.size(); i++){
            String label = labels[i];
            int x_position = values[i].
        renderer.addXTextLabel(x_position, label);
    }

}
```

This will set the labels for the x-axis to whatever you want. The trick is you need to map your data x doubles[] to be a valid axis, ie it goes from a small number to a large number.
Then you graph the formatted x and y dataset. Finally, you change the **labels** of the x-axis to make it look like you want.

Say your data doubles[] is:

```
x = [2,3,0,4,5]
y = [1,2,3,2,1]
```

Then change it to:

```
 x = [1,2,3,4,5]
 y = [1,2,3,2,1](can stay the same)
 labels = ["2","3","0","4","5"]
```

Graph the changed x and y, and then just replace the x labels